# C fcntl() not working? Checking if file is locked or not

Tags: c, locked

So this program creates one file called `testlock` and set the F_RDLCK and F_WRLCK to some regions of the file. The code is below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
        const char *tfile = "testlock";
        char *byte_to_write = "Z";
        struct flock reg1;
        struct flock reg2;
        int byte_count;
        int res;

        int fd = open(tfile, O_RDWR | O_CREAT , 0666);
        if(fd) {
                for(byte_count = 0; byte_count < 100; byte_count++) {
                        (void)write(fd, byte_to_write, 1);
                }
        }

        reg1.l_type = F_RDLCK;
        reg1.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
        reg1.l_start = 10;
        reg1.l_len = 20;

        reg2.l_type = F_WRLCK;
        reg2.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
        reg2.l_start = 0;
        reg2.l_len = 100;

        printf("Proceso %d\n", getpid());
        res = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &reg1);
        if(res != -1) printf("Falló el bloqueo de la reg1 %s\n", strerror(errno));
        res = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &reg2);
        if(res != -1) printf("Falló el bloqueo de la reg2 %s\n", strerror(errno));

        sleep(5);

        printf("Proceso %d\n", getpid());
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To check the first program I have another where I want to check the lock type of the file, and if it's unlocked, write some words on it.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(argc != 2) {
                printf("Vuelve a ejecutar el programa especificando un fichero\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        struct flock fs, fs2;

        // Configuramos el struct que queremos usar para escribir
        fs.l_type = F_WRLCK;
        fs.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
        fs.l_start = 0;
        fs.l_len = 0;
        fs.l_pid = getpid();

        int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_CREAT);
        if(!fd) {
            perror("Error\n");
        } else {
                memset(&fs2, 0, sizeof(fs2));
                int res = fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fs2);
                if(res != -1) {
                        perror("F_GETLK ha fallado\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else {
                        if(fs2.l_type != F_UNLCK) {
                                printf("Tipo de cerrojo: bloqueado\n");
                                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                        } else if(fs2.l_type == F_RDLCK || fs2.l_type == F_WRLCK) {
                                printf("Tipo de cerrojo: desbloqueado\n");
                                fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fs);
                                write(fd, "helloworld", 10);
                                sleep(30);
                                printf("Liberando cerrojo...");
                                fs.l_type = F_UNLCK;
                                fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fs);
                        }
                }
        }
        close(fd);
        return 0;
}
```

The problems are:

- On the first program, I always get the messages "Falló el bloqueo de
  la reg1" y "Falló el bloqueo de la reg2", so fcntl() return -1, but
  `errno` contains "Success", I don't know why. It can be seen on the
  image below.

[image: fcntrl() return -1]

- On the second program, when I try to get the lockl type of the ´testlock´ file created before, I always got the same message "Tipo de cerrojo: bloqueado" (locked), it can be seen on the image below.

[image: locked]

So if anyone could help please I'll apreciate it so much, and if there's anything wrong on the code please let me know, any help will be apreciated!

Comment: The logic in your if's is inverted, you should test `if (res == -1) ...` instead of `!=`. fcntl is most likely returning 0 (success) on both cases.

Comment: That's true man, thanks!

Comment: another logic oops in the code:  when the call to `open()` fails, the code is not exited.  so tries to execute everything after the `if()` statement closes

Comment: the second posted code calls: `close(fd);` even if the prior call to `open()` failed

Comment: regarding: `perror("Error\n");`  This does not inform the user of what happened.  Suggest: `perror("open using command line arg failed");`

Comment: when calling `write()` and/or `fcntl()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Vuelve a ejecutar el programa especificando un fichero\n");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` 2) when the user enters an invalid number of command line parameters, the typical response is to output a USAGE message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <filename>\n", argv[0] );

Comment: please do NOT post screen shots.  Rather copy/paste the text into your question